# Typescript 3.2 upgrade and Response body in lib.dom.d.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I just upgraded to Angular 7 and Typescript 3.2.2. 
One of my spec tests of jasmine is erring now

```
httpMock.expectOne({method: 'PUT'}).flush(new Response({status: 200}));
```

the error says:

> Argument of type '{ status: number; }' is not assignable to parameter
>   of types 'BodyInit'. Object literal may only specify known properties,
>   and status does not exist in type BodyInit

I'm using:

1. @typeScript 3.2.2
2. @types/jasmine 3.3.9 (latest)
3. @types/node 11.10.5 (latest)

am I still using a package that should get updated?

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work

```
httpMock.expectOne({method: 'PUT'}).flush(new Response({status: 200}));
```

I verified that I get an error when set to 404